# How do I make stacked bar chart on amcharts interactive?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have written some code in amcharts.js to create stacked bar charts (with data as a parameter) and a pie chart.

The code can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/akashdmukherjee/myd363tw/30/

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#chartdiv {
    width       : 100%;
    height      : 500px;
    font-size   : 11px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var year_wise_continent_breakdown_data = 
[
{"year": 2003,"europe": 2.5,"namerica": 2.5,"asia": 2.1,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast":0.2,"africa": 0.1},
{"year": 2004,"europe": 2.6,"namerica": 2.7,"asia": 2.2,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast": 0.3,"africa": 0.1}
, {"year": 2005,"europe": 2.8,"namerica": 2.9,"asia": 2.4,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast": 0.3,"africa": 0.1}
];

var quarter_wise_continent_breakdown_data_for_2003 = 
[
{"year": "Q1","europe": 0.5,"namerica": 2.1,"asia": 1.1,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast":0.2,"africa": 0.1},
{"year": "Q2","europe": 2.6,"namerica": 2.7,"asia": 3.2,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast": 0.3,"africa": 0.1}
, {"year": "Q3","europe": 2.8,"namerica": 1.7,"asia": 1.4,"lamerica": 1.3,"meast": 1.3,"africa": 2.1}
];

var quarter_wise_continent_breakdown_data_for_2004 = 
[
{"year": "Q1","europe": 1.5,"namerica": 2.1,"asia": 1.1,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast":0.2,"africa": 0.1},
{"year": "Q2","europe": 4.6,"namerica": 2.7,"asia": 3.2,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast": 0.3,"africa": 0.1}
, {"year": "Q3","europe": 5.8,"namerica": 1.7,"asia": 1.4,"lamerica": 1.3,"meast": 1.3,"africa": 2.1}
];

var quarter_wise_continent_breakdown_data_for_2005 = 
[
{"year": "Q1","europe": 3.9,"namerica": 2.1,"asia": 1.1,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast":0.2,"africa": 0.1},
{"year": "Q2","europe": 2.1,"namerica": 2.7,"asia": 3.2,"lamerica": 0.3,"meast": 0.3,"africa": 0.1}
, {"year": "Q3","europe": 0.8,"namerica": 1.7,"asia": 1.4,"lamerica": 1.3,"meast": 1.3,"africa": 2.1}
];

var continent_breakdown_data = [ 
    {"country": "UK", "litres": 99},
    {"country": "Belgium","litres": 60},
    { "country": "The Netherlands","litres": 50}
];

var make_pieChart_from_continent_breakdown_data = function(selected_year, selected_region){
    AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "pie",
        "theme": "none",
        "dataProvider": continent_breakdown_data,
        "valueField": "litres",
        "titleField": "country",
        "exportConfig":{    
          menuItems: [{
          icon: '/lib/3/images/export.png',
          format: 'png'   
          }]  
        }
    });
};

var make_stackedBars_chart = function(data_for_stackedBars_chart){
    AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "none",
        "legend": {
            "horizontalGap": 10,
            "maxColumns": 1,
            "position": "right",
            "useGraphSettings": true,
            "markerSize": 10
        },
        "dataProvider": data_for_stackedBars_chart,
        "valueAxes": [{
            "stackType": "regular",
            "axisAlpha": 0.3,
            "gridAlpha": 0
        }],
        "graphs": [{
            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "labelText": "[[value]]",
            "lineAlpha": 0.3,
            "title": "Europe",
            "type": "column",
            "fillColors": "#3C3C3C",
            "valueField": "europe"
        }, {
            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "labelText": "[[value]]",
            "lineAlpha": 0.3,
            "title": "North America",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#000000",
            "valueField": "namerica"
        }, {
            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "labelText": "[[value]]",
            "lineAlpha": 0.3,
            "title": "Asia-Pacific",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#000000",
            "valueField": "asia"
        }, {
            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "labelText": "[[value]]",
            "lineAlpha": 0.3,
            "title": "Latin America",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#000000",
            "valueField": "lamerica"
        }, {
            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "labelText": "[[value]]",
            "lineAlpha": 0.3,
            "title": "Middle-East",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#000000",
            "valueField": "meast"
        }, {
            "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "labelText": "[[value]]",
            "lineAlpha": 0.3,
            "title": "Africa",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#000000",
            "valueField": "africa"
        }],
        "categoryField": "year",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "gridPosition": "start",
            "axisAlpha": 0,
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "position": "left"
        },
        "exportConfig":{
            "menuTop":"20px",
            "menuRight":"20px",
            "menuItems": [{
            "icon": '/lib/3/images/export.png',
            "format": 'png'   
            }]  
        }
    })
};

//****************************************************************************
// RENDER CHARTS
//****************************************************************************
make_stackedBars_chart(year_wise_continent_breakdown_data);
////make_pieChart_from_continent_breakdown_data(2005, "Asia-Pacific");
```

If you notice, I create stacked bar charts using make_stackedBars_chart() function by passing in data. From my code, there are four options I can pass as data for the stacked bar chart:
1. year_wise_continent_breakdown_data
2. quarter_wise_continent_breakdown_data_for_2003
3. quarter_wise_continent_breakdown_data_for_2004
4. quarter_wise_continent_breakdown_data_for_2003

I could also create a pie chart instead using the function make_pieChart_from_continent_breakdown_data(selected_year, selected_region). The pie chart, for simplicity here, uses only one piece of data that's defined as the continent_breakdown_data variable.

The first view that an user of this 'dashboard' would see is the year-wise trends broken down by continents. This is the page that's renders when you open the jsfiddle link. This is made possible by a function call make_stackedBars_chart(year_wise_continent_breakdown_data);

***But now is the fun part.***

How do I make this interactive?
Let's start with the first view.
[image]

When the user single-clicks on the first column (data for year 2003), or second column (data for year 2004), or third column (data for year 2005), I want the selected column to be highlighted in Grey. Something like this.
[image]
My hope is that this can be set by setting the fillColors attribute of the graph object in the function. But how?

Next, when the user double-clicks on the selected column, the user should be able to drill-down to a new stacked bar chart which shows category breakdown but trending over Quarters of the selected year. So, let's say the user selected year 2005. When they single-clicked, it turned grey. After single-clicking or before single-clicking, if they double-click the year 2005 column, a new stacked bar chart is loaded with an additional button on top to go back to the previous chart. My understanding is that this needs to be done using a function call of make_stackedBars_chart(quarter_wise_continent_breakdown_data_for_2005);
This should look something like this:[image]

Once this, is done user should be able to click on the top button to go back from there to the old chart into this view.
[image]

Fine. So the user saw year-wise view and quarter-wise view. But, now they want to select only one category (Asia-Pacific region) of year 2005 and see some other data specific to that. Selecting any portion on the chart should first collect the category (region/continent in this case) they have selected and the year they have selected. The selected region should be colored grey on a single click. 
[image]
On a double click before/after the single-click on  this portion of Asia-Pacific in 2005, this information should be passed onto a function that creates a pie chart accordingly. For this, a function call of this could be made
make_pieChart_from_continent_breakdown_data(2005, "Asia-Pacific"); The resultant graph should also have a button on top to go back to the original view. It should look something like this.
[image]

Clicking on 'Go Back', they should be redirected to the original year-wise stacked bar chart.
[image]

Comment: Can someone tell me why is this being voted down?

Comment: Firstly, this is a badly structured question. It's not fair to expect people to read a wall of text before understanding what it is you need help with. Try to reduce your question to a small snippet that clearly demonstrates the problem, and say upfront what you need help with. Secondly, it's very bad etiquette to add irrelevant tags to questions - people who have subscribed to e.g. angularjs and ractivejs get alerted, even though this has absolutely nothing to do with either library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You should follow this example on drill down data**: http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/drill-down-column-chart/

**Key points**: generate data of quarter data as subdata for the yeardata and attach a click event to the chart to catch clicks on the bar to open next level.

**Structure is like this**:

```
data = [{country : "Country1", data1 : "value1", data2 : "value2", 
        subdata [{ country : "Country1", data1.1 : "value1.1", data2.1 : "data2.1"},
                 {country : "Country1", data1.2 : "value1.2", data2.2 : "data2.2"}]}]
```

and click event:

```
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", function (event) {
    if (event.item.dataContext.subdata != undefined) {
        event.chart.dataProvider = event.item.dataContext.subdata;
        event.chart.validateData();
     }
 });
```

**This example shows how to change chart types onclick**: http://www.amcharts.com/tips/switching-chart-type-fly-serial-pie/

**Relevant points:** You can have other type of chart on screen hidden, and onclick makes you change between charts:

```
 document.getElementById('chartdiv').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('chartdiv2').style.display = 'block';
```

**For double click, catch the following event**: http://www.amcharts.com/tips/simulate-doubleclick-map-object/

**Pointers:**

```
 map.addListener("clickMapObject", function (event) {
     if ( false !== map.clickedObject && map.clickedObject === event.mapObject ) {
          // doubleckick
          map.clickedObject = false;
          alert('doubleclick');
     } else {
          clearTimeout( map.clickedObjectTimeout );
          map.clickedObject = event.mapObject;
          map.clickedObjectTimeout = setTimeout( function () {
               map.clickedObject = false;
               }, 500 );
      }
 });
```

**Final notes**: *These are some pointers where you have to make the solution by your own. Markups are taken (almost) directly from the linked examples, so event/element names will vary on your need. Maybe you at least get started with these.*